# unable to play a wav file using ALSA api

Tags: audio, alsa

I am reading a wav file and trying to play it with alsa api using writei() method.
Wav file header has following values

```
Audio Format: 1 (PCM)
Num Channels: 1
Sample Rate: 11025
Byte Rate: 11025
Block Align: 1
Bits Per Sample: 8
Subchunk2 id: 0x61746164
Subchunk2 Size: 24569
```

I did not change buffer  size or period size. Period size for my hw device is 4096 (I read it using snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size() )

Call to writei() looks like

```
//buff_size = period_size * size of each frame = 4096 * 1 bytes;
int16_t* buff = (int16_t *) malloc(buff_size);


for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
     memcpy(buff, &samples[i*period_size], buff_size);

    if (err = snd_pcm_writei(pcm, buff, period_size) == -EPIPE) {
    printf("XRUN.\n");
    snd_pcm_prepare(pcm);
    } else if (err < 0) {
    printf("ERROR. Can't write to PCM device. %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }

}
```

As wav file is 8-bit PCM Mono, frame size is 1 byte and so this file's data size is 24569 frames. Using default period_size, buffer size for writei() = period_size * channels = 4096.
So I need 6 calls to writei() to play the entire file. But when I do that I cannot hear anything. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Buffer and period sizes are typically not fixes; you are supposed to select appropriate values. You do not need to write data in period-sized chunks. Your error checks are wrong or missing. However, the actual error is likely to be in some other part of your program.

Comment: @CL I used `snd_pcm_drain()` and now I can hear wav file. Now I am trying to figure out why it worked? I know trying out random stuff is not good way but I could not find good documentation on alsa, so just trying to figure out from examples I found online. I am sorry about bad error checks but I just wanted to get basic code working.

Comment: The actual error is in the part of your program that set the start threshold.